# Setting COM-Port control signals persistently

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

We are turning a remote system on or off by setting the DTR line of a serial COM port (pins other than DTR and GND are left unconnected). The remote system is turned on when the voltage is less than -3.5V, otherwise it's turned off.

By default DTR is turned off and the pin outputs -9V (i.e. remote system is turned on). Using the SerialPort class of .NET, turning the remote system off is as simple as

```
var port = new SerialPort("COMx");
port.Open();
port.DtrEnable = true;
```

My problem is that, as soon as the port object is being disposed, the default state of DTR is restored (OFF) and therefore the remote system is turned back on. Of course this is not a problem as long as the "control program" runs because I can keep the port object alive. However, how can I keep DTR enabled when the user closes the program?

I figured it can't be done using the .NET class so tried to use Win32 api functions instead:

```
var handle = CreateFile(sPortName, 0x80000000 | 0x40000000, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 4, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
var config = new DCB();

GetCommState(handle, ref config);
config.Flags = 0x11; //set fDTRControl and fBinary
SetCommState(handle, ref config);
CloseHandle(handle);
```

Unfortunately, the call to 'CloseHandle' also restores the default settings of the COM port so this code doesn't work either.

Is there a way to make this work other than creating a permanently running background service?

Comment: It is normal for SerialPort to turn DTR off, like it should, you'd have to use Environment.FailFast() to prevent the normal cleanup from happening.  It is not normal that pinvoking CloseHandle() restores the signal state.  You'd have to go shopping for another USB emulator perhaps.

Comment: @HansPassant I found out that the DTR state is indeed remembered after calling CloseHandle. However, the stored state is only applied to the output pin when there is an open file handle to the device. As soon as the file handle is closed, the DTR line is always turned off. I tried this both with a built-in RS232 port and with a USB/RS232 converter and the behaviour is the same.